# React: Detect delete key pressed on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can get the `onKeyPress` event to fire from the canvas

```
         <canvas
            id='canvas'
            ref={canvasRef}
            className='canvas'
            tabIndex={0}
            onKeyPress={(e: React.KeyboardEvent) => setKeyDown(e)}
          />
```

But the `setKeyDown` function thst recieves the event doesnt seem to fire when I press `delete` while other keys do log values, I want to know if the `delete` key was pressed.

```
  const setKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    console.log(event.key);
  };
```

I have tried using `any` as the type but I get the same results

Comment: Typing the event does not change the behavior of the application, it just helps typescript to detect errors. Let me add the javascript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onKeyPress` doesn't capture the delete key. To capture delete key presses use `onKeyDown` event.

`onKeyDown={(e: React.KeyboardEvent) => setKeyDown(e)}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture onKeyDown event

your event handler be like

```
   onDelete = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 46) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    }
};
```

Keycode for delete key is 46